# WC API: Invalid JSON RETURNED

Tags: json, api, wc

what am i doing wrong here?! It's two days since i've killed Google and stackoverflow... I can't figure it out :(((

I've checked online the returned body json (didn't paste it here cause it's long) and is a valid json... where is the problem?!

No cache plugins installed, same request in postman returns an OK result, testing the request URL directly in browser returns an ok result, everyting is fine except when im using in my project...

Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClientException Object
(
[request:Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClientException:private] => Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\Request Object
(
[url:Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\Request:private] => https://www.viatainrawz.ro/wp-json/wc/v3/products
[method:Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\Request:private] => GET
[parameters:Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\Request:private] => Array
(
)

```
        [headers:Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\Request:private] => Array
            (
                [Accept] => application/json
                [Content-Type] => application/json
                [User-Agent] => WooCommerce API Client-PHP/1.0.2
            )

        [body:Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\Request:private] => 
    )

[response:Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClientException:private] => Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\Response Object
    (
        [code:Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\Response:private] => 200
        [headers:Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\Response:private] => Array
            (
                [date] => Mon, 31 Aug 2020 09:26:42 GMT
                [content-type] => application/json; charset=UTF-8
                [vary] => Accept-Encoding
                [x-robots-tag] => noindex
                [x-content-type-options] => nosniff
                [access-control-expose-headers] => X-WP-Total, X-WP-TotalPages, Link
                [access-control-allow-headers] => Authorization, X-WP-Nonce, Content-Disposition, Content-MD5, Content-Type
                [expires] => Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
                [cache-control] => no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
                [x-wp-total] => 49
                [x-wp-totalpages] => 5
                [link] => <https://viatainrawz.ro/wp-json/wc/v3/products?page=2>; rel="next"
                [allow] => GET, POST
                [server] => ClausWeb-nginx
                [cluster-host] => server46.romania-webhosting.com
            )

        
    )

[message:protected] => Invalid JSON returned
[string:Exception:private] => 
[code:protected] => 200
[file:protected] => /home/vreaumob/worker.vreaumobila.ro/vendor/automattic/woocommerce/src/WooCommerce/HttpClient/HttpClient.php
[line:protected] => 303
[trace:Exception:private] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [file] => /home/vreaumob/worker.vreaumobila.ro/vendor/automattic/woocommerce/src/WooCommerce/HttpClient/HttpClient.php
                [line] => 346
                [function] => lookForErrors
                [class] => Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClient
                [type] => ->
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [file] => /home/vreaumob/worker.vreaumobila.ro/vendor/automattic/woocommerce/src/WooCommerce/HttpClient/HttpClient.php
                [line] => 382
                [function] => processResponse
                [class] => Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClient
                [type] => ->
                [args] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [file] => /home/vreaumob/worker.vreaumobila.ro/vendor/automattic/woocommerce/src/WooCommerce/Client.php
                [line] => 82
                [function] => request
                [class] => Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClient
                [type] => ->
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => products
                        [1] => GET
                        [2] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [3] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [file] => /home/vreaumob/worker.vreaumobila.ro/apitest.php
                [line] => 24
                [function] => get
                [class] => Automattic\WooCommerce\Client
                [type] => ->
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => products
                    )

            )

    )

[previous:Exception:private] =>
```

)
Invalid JSON returned

Answer (score -1):

The code i use:

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Automattic\WooCommerce\Client;
use Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClientException;
try {
  $woocommerce = new Client( 'https://www.viatainrawz.ro','XX', 'XX',
        [
            'verify_ssl' => false,
            'version' => 'wc/v3'
        ]
    );
   print_r($woocommerce->get('products'));

} catch (HttpClientException $e) {
    \print_r($e);
    \print_r($e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL);
    \print_r('Code: ' . $e->getResponse()->getCode() . PHP_EOL);
    \print_r('Body: ' . $e->getResponse()->getBody() . PHP_EOL);
}
```